# Is there a way to run multiple Grails apps on the same web server without running into PermGen errors?

Tags: grails, jetty, permgen

We're developing a few Grails applications, and deploying the WARs on Jetty.  When we run each of the applications one at a time, they hover at around 200 - 300 MB of memory, which is perfectly acceptable.  But, adding any more applications increases the memory footprint... by a lot.  Once we have our three applications running, we usually end up crashing around 900 MB.

All three of the applications have Quartz jobs.  I've tried increasing the PermGen size, but to no avail.  And adding more memory to the web server isn't an option.  Is there an easy way to bring down the size of the Grails apps?

Comment: similar question with good information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535458/grails-application-hogging-too-much-memory

Comment: Thanks, that got me started in a good direction.

Answer (score 0):

we have written our custom ContextCleanupListener to clean all garbage.