# Does Cloudfoundry support apps that require larger memory?

Tags: grails, permgen, cloud-foundry

I have been developing a website using grails and demo'ing it using Cloudfoundry.  Grails and Cloudfoundry are awesome!  The are easy to use with support from grails plugins and tools in STS.

My app uses MySQL, MongoDB, SpringSecurity, and more.  I have only used it with one user logged in and I periodically get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`

I have increased the memory to 1G using the grails plugin.  I tried to set JAVA_OPTS to increase the memory and this did not work.

I am going to examine where the memory is being used, but it seems that one user and a tiny set of demo data should not be pushing the memory limits.

Does Cloudfoundry support apps that require larger memory?

After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535458/grails-application-hogging-too-much-memory) I set the MaxPermSize to 512M and I no longer have out of memory errors.  I'm using grails cmdline on windows and I cannot get more than one JAVA_OPTS set, only the first in a list is used. `grails cf-env-add JAVA_OPTS "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512M -Xmx512M"` This one setting has added stability to my demo site.

Comment: thanx Mark .... I was stuck here. Adding environment and increasing permSize resolved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

The original poster has an answer in the original question:

> After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535458/grails-application-hogging-too-much-memory) post I set the MaxPermSize to 512M and I no longer have out of memory errors.  I'm using grails cmdline on windows and I cannot get more than one JAVA_OPTS set, only the first in a list is used. `grails cf-env-add JAVA_OPTS "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512M -Xmx512M"` This one setting has added stability to my demo site

Answer (score 0):

It's a PermGen space, and at this case it's in development mode only (or when you're using Tomcat and redeploy your app few times, its not a CloudFoundry case).

See official FAQ: [OMG I get OutOfMemoryErrors or PermGen Space errors when running Grails in development mode. What do I do?](http://www.grails.org/FAQ#Q%3a%20OMG%20I%20get%20OutOfMemoryErrors%20or%20PermGen%20Space%20errors%20when%20running%20Grails%20in%20development%20mode.%20What%20do%20I%20do?)

Comment: I will try that, but my problem does not happen in development and not during deployment.  The problem happens after I successfully deploy on cloudfoundry and after a single user uses the site for 5 - 10 minutes.

Comment: Oh, so it's something different. Never saw permgen space error on runnning app. Does your app generates a lot of new classes (or maybe dynamic closures) on the fly?

Comment: I modified my original post with the answer

Comment: btw, it's better to find cause. I can help for a while, 512mb for permgen is realy really big amount, but app still can fail at any moment.